# How to create a custom ColorPicker widget in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget, qt5, qt6

I am making a desktop app with Qt6.2 and C++ and I want to create a ColorPicker widget that is much like QColorPicker.
I want it to look like this:

[image]

This is Evernote's color picker. For some reason, Qt6.2 does not have QColorPicker and I don't know where to get it from. I am interested however in creating my own custom widget to look like the picture above.

My first intuition was to use a grid layout and place buttons in them. It seemed so tedious to set each button's stylesheet and connect every button. I did not get any intuition as to how I can reduce redundancy. I thought there has to be another way. This looks fundamentally like a ComboBox, though it has a different layout.

How can I implement this colorpicker? While some will suggest using QColorPicker (I don't know where to get it from as its not shipped in Qt), I am actually interested as to how a widget like this is implemented.

Comment: Qt offers [QColorDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolordialog.html). Does that do what you want?

Comment: QDialog with windowFlag Qt::Popup + QTableWidget with colored cells + QPushButtons